# Expectation in stationary time series ${X_t}$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, self-learning, time-series

> Let us assume now that $\{X_t\}$ is a stationary time series with
>   $$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+Z_t \qquad t=0,\pm 1,\dots,$$ where $\{Z_t\}\sim
> > WN(0,\sigma^2)$ (White noise), $|\phi|<1$ and $\{Z_t\}$ is
>   uncorrelated with $X_s$ for each $s<t$. Show that $EX_t=0$.

What I did is
$$E[X_t]=E[\phi X_{t-1}+Z_t]\Rightarrow E[X_t]=E[\phi X_{t-1}]$$
and

$$E[X_t]=\phi E[X_{t-1}]\Leftrightarrow E[X_t]=E[X_{t-1}]=0$$

because if a time series $\{X_t\}$ is stationary then $\mu_X(t)$ is independent of $t$.

Is that right?

Comment: I believe the definition of $X_t$ should read "...$t=0,\pm1,\ldots,$.

Comment: @Math1000 What you mean?

Comment: $$X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + Z_t,\ t=0,\pm1,\ldots, $$

Comment: your proof is correct.

Comment: Sorry to ruin the party but it is impossible to know, from what you write, whether you understood the argument which shows that $E(X_t)=0$ for every $t$, or not. The odd paragraph from your post is: [$E[X_t]=\phi E[X_{t-1}]\Leftrightarrow E[X_t]=E[X_{t-1}]=0$ because if a time series $\{X_t\}$ is stationary then $\mu_X(t)$ is independent of $t$]. Recall that proofs should be non ambiguous...